# how to post on multiple facebook friends wall using Facebook api FB.UI

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-javascript-sdk

how can post on my facebook friends wall using FB.UI

my code is

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
        to:['405631902932995,626150064162274'],
        caption: 'An example caption'
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

i am getting error like

```
    API Error Code: 100
    API Error Description: Invalid parameter
    Error Message: ["100004585663846,100003018593104"] does not resolve to a valid user ID
```

Answer (score 2):

That parameter only allows to enter one ID, not an array of them. Meaning, what you want to achieve is not possible at all, you can only specify one friend.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

You can also use the Send Dialog to send a message to a friend: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

The same applies to the "to" parameter, you can only specify one recipient.

Comment: i want to send to multiple users how can i send